# Is there a connection between shoelace formula and Stokes theorem?

Tags: integration, geometry, discrete-mathematics, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

The [shoelace-formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) is a method to calculate the area of a polygon. It is given as
$$
A = 1/2 \sum_i{(x_i-x_{i+1})*(y_i+y_{i+1})}
$$
for cyclical $i$. Expanding the product yields the terms $x_i y_i - x_{i+1}y_{i+1}$ which cancel with the next and previous terms of the sum, resulting in:
$$
A = 1/2 \sum_i x_i y_{i+1} - x_{i+1} y_i = 1/2 \sum_i |\vec{X_i} \times \vec{X_{i+1}}|
$$

Which prompted my intuition to look for connections with [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) but so far I got nowhere. Is this just a coincidence and Stokes' has nothing to do with this? I can see how this is basically a discrete version of [Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), but that just doesn't feel like any kind of deep understanding. And yes, I'm asking to satisfy my curiosity.

The best concrete question I could think of is:

Is there a field $F$ for which Stokes' theorem and the shoelace formula coincide for infinitesimally close polygon-corners?

---

What I've got so far:

The absolute value of a cross product is cumbersome and can be replaced by either a dot-product with the surface-normal or limiting the calculation to the z-axis instead.

So either $|\vec{X_i} \times \vec{X_{i+1}}| = (\vec{X_i} \times \vec{X_{i+1}}) * \left({\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\ 1\end{smallmatrix}}\right) $ or use $A \simeq\left({\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\ A\end{smallmatrix}}\right)$.

To get from a sum to an integral, an infinitesimal delta is required. The delta is hidden in the cross-product:
$$
\vec{X_i}\times\vec{X_{i+1}} = \vec{X_i}\times(\vec{X_i} + \vec{\Delta_i}) = \vec{X_i}\times\vec{\Delta_i}
$$
taking the limit $\vec{\Delta} \rightarrow 0$:
$$
A = \vec{n} * 1/2 \int_{\partial A} \vec { X } \times \vec{\partial A}
$$
The area $A$ can easily be interpreted as a surface integral over 1:
$$
\int \int_A 1 = A
$$
Or, more in line with the concept of a vector-field:
$$
\int \int_A \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\ 1\end{smallmatrix}\right) = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\ A\end{smallmatrix}\right)
$$
All the elements are there, but my main problem is the cross product is on the wrong side. I could construct a field with unit curl everywhere to satisfy the left hand side, but then I don't know what to do on the right.

Comment: Which version of Stoke's theorem are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I've added a link to the wikipedia-page.

Comment: Did you see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_calculation? This basically shows how Green's theorem yields the shoelace formula. And Stoke's theorem is for three-dimensional surfaces, whereas your polygon is two-dimensional.

Comment: Using Green's theorem: This doesn't explain/help understand anything. I have an intuitive understanding of Stoke's though: "total curl in the area is equal to line-integral of the brim" (On a slightly deeper level than fits in a comment so I hope my point came across)

Comment: That is precisely the intuition for Green's theorem too---Green's theorem is just the two dimensional special case of Stokes'.

Comment: What about using $F(x,y) = (-y, 0)$. Then, the two-dimensional curl is exactly $1$.

Comment: @prets I understand Green's is just the (flat?) 2D-case of Stoke's, but the implication of shuffling the cross product from one side to the other yields an identity I don't understand/have intuition for. Maybe the question about Stoke's is the wrong avenue and what I'm asking is whether $\int\int_A (0,0,1) = \vec n 1/2 \int_{\partial A} \vec{X}\times\vec{\partial A}$ has more global applications/implications. Most plausibly Stoke's already implies something like $\int\int_A \nabla F = \int_{\partial A} F \times \vec{\partial A}$ but I can't see the way to get there.